# How do you get jconsole charts to show decimals?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

If you return a double or float from your MBean jconsole seems to round it down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to return a Double or Float instead.  Jconsole is looking for the wrapper classes to determine when to show decimal places.

Comment: After digging though the source code I thought maybe I could save others the trouble